# how to set Custom Select and MultiSelect value while Product add Programatically Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute, select

I am working on to create a simple product programmatically.

I have created 2 custom Attribute

1. Select(select_testing)
2. MultiSelect(multiselect_testing)

select_testing attribute value ==> 1, 2, ,3, 4.
multiselect_testing attribute value --> 1, 2, 3, 4.

So, I try to add Product using following code.

```
  $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
  $simple_product = $_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
  $simple_product->setSku('test-sku');
  $simple_product->setName('SimpleProduct');
  $simple_product->setRkTesting('Rk Testing');
  $simple_product->setSelectTesting('1');
  $simple_product->setMultiselectTesting(array("1","2"));
  $simple_product->setYesTesting(1);
  $simple_product->save();
```

But, Select and Multiselect attribute value not save.

Suggest me, how to add Select and multiselect Attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend
```

as 'backend_model' for your "multiple" attribute

and update attribute by follow:

```
$_product->addAttributeUpdate('attribute_code', 'value', $storeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the values comma separated not array.
 $simple_product->setMultiselectTesting('1,2,3');